# javascript variable scope - how can i work around this?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, asynchronous

I have an input field, where a user can enter an `INPUTVALUE`, this `INPUTVALUE` gets checked for correctness against a reg-ex, then sent off to a php file, which will do calculations with it, and return either 0 (meaning the `INPUTVALUE` was not valid) or a `RETURNVALUE`. This `RETURNVALUE` should be displayed in an element on the website with the id `#VALUEINFO`. Also I would like this `RETURNVALUE` returned by my function `get_value_by_input()`. In order to check what was returned, I am displaying an alert first.

(A practical application for this could be for example a coupon code on an order... put in your coupon code, we check it in the database, it returns the value of the coupon or 0 if it was not a valid coupon code.)

My problem is, I must be messing up something with the variable scope in Javascript, because eventhough my `#VALUEINFO` displays the correct `RETURNVALUE`, the alert will always say `no returnvalue specified`.

```
function get_value_by_input()
{
    var returnvalue;
    var valueinfo = $('#valueinfo');
    valueinfo.text('');
    var inputvalue = $("input[name='inputvalue']").val();
    var correctinput = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/i;
    if( inputvalue.length > 0 && correctinput.test(inputvalue))
    {
        $.post('ajax/valuecheck.php', {inputvalue_test: inputvalue}, function(is_valid){
            if(is_valid == 0)
            {
                       valueinfo.text('Sorry, this input is not working...');
                       returnvalue = 0;
            }
            if(is_valid != 0)
            {
                      valueinfo.text('the returned value for your input is '+is_valid);
                      returnvalue = is_valid;
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        if(inputvalue)
        {
            valueinfo.text('Invalid input.');
            returnvalue = 0;
        }
    }

    if(returnvalue)
    {
        alert('the value for this input was was '+returnvalue);
        return returnvalue;
    }
    else
    {
        alert('no returnvalue specified.');
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Again:
**Why does this code ALWAYS alert 'no returnvalue specified' eventhough #VALUEINFO gives me the correct returnvalue?**

I assume this has to do with the if block, I read that javascript will not ignore the setting of any variables within if blocks, even if the condition is not fulfilled... But how else could I pass the value to #valueinfo and return it at the same time?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! :-)

**EDIT:**

Well, yes it has nothing to do with variable scope, but it's about Asynchronus-jax. 
I ended up restructuring my code... `get_value_by_input()` is now more of a `process_input()` function. First the `INPUTVALUE` is checked for correctness, and only if there were no errors `$.post(...` is called. The value returned by the php file is then used immediately within the callback function, rather then to be returned and then used from another function... Unfortunately I couldn't get my brain wrapped around working with `.done()` or something similar, guess I've been working too long on this today already... -.- Maybe next time. It works for now :)

Comment: That's not a scope issue. It's an asynchronous issue. You need to use the return value in your callback, functions that the callback calls, or callbacks to a Deferred object that guarantees that the Ajax callback has already executed. You're currently trying to use the `returnvalue` before the callback executes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: Yep, quite possible... Sorry!

Comment: I guess I was quite off track... thanks for the comments. I'll include in my answer how I worked around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to handle the return value in a callback (since you're dealing with an asynchronous call).

This might give you a better understanding on how to solve the problem:

```
function getReturnValue(inputvalue, callback){
    $.post('ajax/valuecheck.php', { 'inputvalue_test': inputvalue}, callback);
}

var inputvalue = $("input[name='inputvalue']").val();

getReturnValue(inputvalue, function(is_valid){
    //handle is_valid here
    //it's the data returned from the ajax call
});
```

There are a lot of similar [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success).

Comment: I guess I was quite off track... Thanks for the help!